# Post stories (through Facebook App and Game Group API) as the app using PHP SDK

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-group, facebook-game-groups

How I can post stories(through Facebook App and Game Group API) as the app using PHP SDK ?

I'm getting a permission error :

```
(#200) User does not have sufficient administrative permission for this action on this page
```

I'm using this params:

```
$params = array( 
        'message' => 'test',
        'access_token' => $access_token
    );

    $this->facebook->api('/' .$group_id .'/feed', 'post', $params);
```

Comment: And the access token you are using is the app access token, as described in the documentation?

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to have `publish_actions` and either `user_groups` or `user_managed_groups` permission to post on behalf of a user to app groups.

Secondly, to post on behalf of the app itself to its app group, the access token must be app_access_token and this action must be done on the server side to avoid app token being leaked.